# How to use Arraylist over different classes

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

Im trying to add a dog (nyHund) which is created in a different class, to an Arraylist i created using a constructor in another class, but whenever i try to use the Arraylist in the "register" class, im getting the error that the arraylist name can't be resolved.

First class:

```
    public class Hund {

    private String namn;
    private int ålder;
    private double vikt;
    private String ras;

    public Hund(String hundnamn, int hundålder, String hundras, double hundvikt) {
        this.namn = hundnamn;
        this.ålder = hundålder;
        this.ras = hundras;
        this.vikt = hundvikt;
    }

    public String getNamn() {
        return namn;
    }

    public int getÅlder() {
        return ålder;
    }

    public double getSvanslängd() {
        if (ras=="tax"){
            return 3.7;
        }else{
            return ((vikt*ålder)/10);
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        return namn + "\n" + ålder + "\n"+ras+"\n"+vikt+"\n"+getSvanslängd();
    }
}
```

Second Class

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
public class testning {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hund nyHund = new Hund("Daisy", 13, "labrador", 22.3);
        System.out.println(nyHund.toString());
        Register.läggTillHund(nyHund);



    }

}
```

And the Third class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Register {



    public static void läggTillHund(Hund nyHund){
        hundRegister.add(nyHund);
        System.out.println(nyHund);



    }



    private Register(){
        ArrayList<Hund> hundRegister = new ArrayList<Hund>();
    }


}
```

The problem i am experiencing is with "hundRegister.add(nyHund)"

any thoughts? or pointers where im going wrong? (very new at Java)

Best Regards
Oskar

Answer (score 3):

The `ArrayList` you've created is local to your `Register` constructor.  Declare it inside the class, but outside the constructor, as an instance variable, so it's in scope throughout the class.

```
public class Register {
    private ArrayList<Hund> hundRegister;
    private Register(){
        hundRegister = new ArrayList<Hund>();
    }
}
```

Additionally, it's unclear why the constructor is `private`.  Nothing else can access that constructor.  I would make it `public`.

Also, in `getSvanslängd`, replace `ras=="tax"` with `"tax".equals(ras)`.  See [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

Comment: Thanks! A moment of shame for me then ;) pretty obvious when i see the answer ;)

Comment: Throwing me a NullpointerException, but no compilation errors now though. Im guessing i got some more troubleshooting to do xD